# Create a Directory using Directory.CreateDirectory( ) that gives a warning message when trying to delete or rename

Tags: c#, winforms, security, file, directory

My application creates several text files that contain important data for its working. I am grouping up all these files in a folder. In `Form_load()` I gave `Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\xyz")`, so that a folder is created in a drive which will later include text files, when the application will be delivered to clients. I want to see that the user does not **delete or rename** the folder. A **dialog box** that shows some **warning message** will be helpful. Is it possible with `Directory.CreateDirectory()`?

Comment: Why not just display a normal `MessageBox` after creating the directory?

Comment: Do you want that dialog to appear when your users try to rename or delete created directory, or when it is created in your application? Also, it is better to create that directory somewhere like ApplicationData\YourApplication...

Comment: Not at directory creation. Only when the directory is being deleted or renamed

Comment: @Cdeez Do you mean you're giving them these abilities inside your program, and you want to warn them? If so, what do you expect to happen if someone is modifying the directory outside of your program?

Comment: If these are files that the user shouldn't touch, put them in an appropriate location (a subdirectory under [`SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) would seem indicated). That's already "off-limits" to the user from a conventions perspective - if they delete directories/files in there, they're already asking for applications to misbehave.

Comment: _"I want to see that the user does not delete or rename the folder."_ - what problem are you trying to solve? If a user deletes a vital part of your application, for example its data files, the user should expect the program not to be working anymore.

Comment: Let me make it more clear. Its a GSM modem application. Those text files will contain contacts, messages,... kind of information. So deleting them will not make any difference to the app but the user's data will be lost. Thats why I just needed a warning message kind of functionality

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just warn the user about the importance of this directory. However, you can recreate the directory by performing this kind of check :

```
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
  Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

From this point, you can imagine a mecanism that save the important files in a temporary way, and if the directory is deleted, you recreate it and put the previously saved files in it.

Comment: Yes if there is no directory a new directory will be created and text files are placed into it. But once the directory is deleted containing the files, then all the data is lost. I want to warn the user that he is trying to delete important data. If he still wants to continue that upto him but a warning message is what I want to show

Comment: Look at @Damien_The_Unbeliever , I think it's a good solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might find reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/26/9884331.aspx) helpful.

Second: If I understand your needs correctly, what you want is **much** more painful than you think.
You should **really** consider doing what Damien_The_Unbeliever told you.

However, if you insist: You will need to use C++ (C# will give you and your users a lot of pain) for it, and you will need to "hook" `SHFileOperation` through something like `ICopyHook`. Start by taking a look at [`ICopyHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776049.aspx). It will be a lot of work and a lot of learning, and **I don't think it's worth it**, but there's the info. Good luck.

Comment: Even with the copy hook, it only applies for *shell* operations. There's nothing to stop them from firing up `CMD.EXE` and performing the delete. You'd have to be looking at implementing (I think it's called...) a file system filter driver.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes. I assumed this is enough for the OP to get started, since a determined user can even bypass filter drivers, anyway, and this is already hard enough as-is. (And if he's using the command prompt, he probably knows the consequences of his actions well enough that he should be allowed to 'override' the protection.)

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever: seems like its a quick and easy solution, will go with it. Thanks. @Mehrdad: Thanks for the links but using them seems quite complex so not going with it.